# problem with separate {tidyr} error when using sep=" \ "

Tags: r, escaping, tidyr, backslash

My data set looks like:

```
 head(d.deg_prim2) 

    Valid Date Julian Temp Day Time
1                   255\t19\t-1.338548\t <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
2 ok\t1/4/2018 10:53\t43191.45376\t12.25 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
3 ok\t1/4/2018 12:01\t43191.50081\t12.75 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
4     ok\t1/4/2018 12:31\t43191.5221\t13 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
5  ok\t1/4/2018 13:53\t43191.57877\t13.5 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
6 ok\t1/4/2018 14:28\t43191.60342\t12.75 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
```

I need to separate the "valid" column into 4 columns divided by the symbol backslash .

So I have used:

```
d.deg_prim2 <- d.deg_prim  %>% separate(Valid, sep = "\", into=c("Valid", "Date", "Julian", "Temp"), remove = TRUE)

Error: unexpected symbol in "d.deg_prim2 <- d.deg_prim  %>% separate(Valid, sep = "\", into=c("Valid"
```

When I try other symbols to separate the column like: 1) two backslash or 2) three backslash or 3) four backslash or 4) [\], I obtained the following errors:

```
1) Error in stringi::stri_split_regex(value, sep, n_max) : 
  Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE)
2) Error: unexpected symbol in "d.deg_prim2 <- d.deg_prim  %>% separate(Valid, sep = "\\\", into=c("Valid"
3) Warning message:
Expected 4 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1259 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...]. 
> head(d.deg_prim2) 
                                Valid Date Julian Temp Day Time
1                   255\t19\t-1.338548\t <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
2 ok\t1/4/2018 10:53\t43191.45376\t12.25 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
3 ok\t1/4/2018 12:01\t43191.50081\t12.75 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
4     ok\t1/4/2018 12:31\t43191.5221\t13 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA
5  ok\t1/4/2018 13:53\t43191.57877\t13.5 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  NA   NA

4) Error: '\]' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""[\]"
```

Comment: A couple of quick thoughts: (1) looks like you are using `d.deg_prim` and not `d.deg_prim2` in your example (though data is from `d.deg_prim2`); (2) maybe you want to separate (`sep`) by `\t` instead of just ```\``` (single slash)?

Comment: Thank you soooo much! with \t works perfect! what does "t" mean? Do you know a place where I can read more about these symbols and separate function? Thanks thanks!!!

Comment: Perhaps `\t` refers to "tab"?

Comment: Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) for more info on escape sequences (with `\t` a common delimeter used, such as in tab-separated value or TSV files).